# Google Maps in JSP Document

Tags: google-maps, jsp, geolocation

Could anybody direct me to an example of JSP code displaying a google map? I've got some javascript that works but ideally I would like to feature a map in my pre existing JSP pages.

Many Thanks

Comment: Also I've got the google developer guide but it doesn't give a clear cut example

Comment: JSP is server-side, and has nothing to do with the client-side JavaScript that you will still need to utilize Google Maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put it in a HTML file. Once you got it to work, then rename `.html` to `.jsp` whenever you want to replace some static content by backend-controlled dynamic content with help of EL (those `${}` things).

Do you now see the point of JSP?

Comment: This makes sense thank you. I'm still unsure as to where in the developer guide it implicitly instructs on displaying the map at a given lat/lon...